# Outgoing Calls Receiver an redirecter in andorid, can't catch out going calls

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an android redirect calls application which catches outgoing calls by BroadcastReceiver and redirects them by service.

However i can't find the reason why i can't catch outgoing calls, the function onReceive is never accessed.

My manifest (so that you can see it's not a permissions issue)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.outgoingcall"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".OutgoingCallIntentService" />

</application>
```

OutgoingCallReceiver.java

```
    package com.example.outgoingcall;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private static boolean mStateOutgoingCall;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

            if (mStateOutgoingCall) {
                return;
            }

            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            setResultData(null);

            Log.v(TAG, "tel:" + number);
            Toast.makeText(context, "tel:" + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intentService = new Intent(context, com.example.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallIntentService.class);
            intentService.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            context.startService(intentService);

            mStateOutgoingCall = true;

        } else if (action.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {

            String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            //Toast.makeText(context, phoneState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.v(TAG, "onReceive() " + phoneState);

            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(phoneState)) {
            }
            else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(phoneState)) {
            }
            else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(phoneState)) {
                mStateOutgoingCall = false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

OutgoingCallIntentService.java

```
    package com.example.outgoingcall;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class OutgoingCallIntentService extends IntentService {
    static final public String TAG = OutgoingCallIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

    public OutgoingCallIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public OutgoingCallIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onHandleIntent()");

        Intent intentActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intentActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intentActivity.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(intentActivity);

    }
}
```

please let me know if you see anything that might be the issue.
Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

The code seems to be correct.

However when deploying to a device directly i need to set permissions in my phone:

Apps->specific app->phone on